# SpringFramework /JdbcTemplate: database connection not cleanedup from threadlocal on transaction rollback

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions

In production , we are seeing Spring Framework (Spring-jdbc 4.2.4) not cleaning up the database connection that it stores in a thread local.

Subsequent usages of the same thread leads to jdbcTemplate getting a potentially stale connection (one terminated my mysql server) from threadlocal
instead of getting a new one from the connection pool. When this happens we get a Broken pipe or communication link failure on the connection.

```
WrappedException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet successfully received from the server was 80,416 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to
 the server was 1 milliseconds ago.     [source:]

or

at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1038)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3621)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2429)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2594)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2541)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2499)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1432)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:3617)
... 336 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
```

The problem can be easily reproduced on a single thread with the following code

On mysql server set connection timeout to say 60 sec

mysql > set global wait_timeout = 60

In java code

```
mainMethod() {

  try {

    method1() ;

   } catch(Exception e) {

    method2() // this is the real call
    sleep(80secs)
    method2() // this is there to a simulate another request on same thread

   }


}

@Transactional
method1() {

    jdbcTemplate.execute("select 1") ;
    throw new RuntimeException() ;


}


@Transactional
method2() {

    jdbcTemplate.execute("select 1") ;

}
```

The 2nd call to method2 is there to simulate another request on the same thread after the first call method2 has leaked a db connection to the threadLocal

In debugging the code I observed that jdbcTemplate calls DataSourceUtils.getConnection to get a connection.

DataSourceUtils.getConnection first tries to get a connection from a ThreadLocal. It goes to the dataSource only if there
is no connection in the threadLocal. In this scenario, it finds a terminated (due to timeout) connection in the threadLocal which causes Method2
to fail with a jdbc Broken pipe socket exception.

Changing method2 to @Transactional(propagation = Requires_NEW) did not help.

Is this a SpringFramework bug or should I be doing something differently ? How should the method2 ( the first call to method2) be done so it cleans up its db connection on the threadLocal

Comment: Look around on spring bug tracker and if you don't find an existing one, submit a new bug report.

Comment: Are you using the correct jdbc driver for the database version?

Comment: @JustinKSU This should have nothing to do with the driver or database version. Debugging shows that the connection is stored in the threadlocal by Spring and not cleared out when the transaction rollsback.

Comment: Are you using a connection pool for your database connections? Most implementations will automatically evict unused connections, create new ones as needed, and let you test the connection before passing back to a calling class.

Comment: @MichaelPeacock That's not the issue here. The issue is that a connection is kept in a threadlocal, and it can get stale if enough time passes. The pool isn't involved here (so it can't check whether the connection is valid).

Comment: Usually the pool will handle killing dead connections.  If you are not using a pool, Spring may assume you are going to take care of this task.  When I use Tomcat and an Oracle driver, I tell it what validation query to use to check to see if the connection is still alive before using it again.  if it's dead, it will create a new connection.

Comment: I have updated the sample code to show more clearly that it is the call method2 (1st call ) that fails to clean up the connection in threadLocal

Comment: As @JustinKSU mentions, if you choose not to use a database connection pool, then you need to explicitly manage the connections in your code. Database connections are like file handles in that they're tied to external resources that you need to explicitly maintain (open, close, test for existence, etc) if you're not relying on some other api or framework to maintain these for you.  Are you saying that you are explicitly maintaining your connections in your code, and you are still getting stale connections?

Comment: @MichaelPeacock It's spring that's keeping the connection in a threadlocal. The pool is not involved here (except for getting the initial connection).

Comment: @MichaelPeacock  Spring is managing the database connections. Not my code. After the first call to method2, there is a connection left in the threadLocal that Spring continues to use without going to the dataSource -- in subsequent use of jdbcTemplate in that thread. In the example I show that with a second call to method2.

Comment: I am able to work around the issue by either of these 2 ways (1) running method2 in a new thread (2) Avoid spring jdbcTemplate and using straight JDBC in method2

Comment: Did you submit a bug report?

Comment: @Kayaman I will open a JIRA and post the JIRA here

Comment: Spring will manage creating new connections, and closing them when there's an exception, but the responsibility for making sure the connections are good is deferred to the javax.sql.DataSource implementation you're using when you create your JdbcTemplate. If your DataSource implementation isn't capable of closing stale connections, or if it's not able to test the connections before it allows JdbcTemplate to use them, then you need a different data source implementation. We use one of the many connection pool data sources available, which allows our apps to run for months between restarts.

Comment: @MichaelPeacock Perhaps you are still not understanding the issue. The issue is that Spring is taking a connection out of the connection pool, never returning it to the pool and trying to use it after the database server has terminated the connection. One the pool has handed out a connection to Spring, it is out of the picture - until spring return the connection or asks for another one

Comment: Opened JIRA https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15194

Comment: Sorry @daManja - From the earlier comments, I got the impression that you were not using a connection pool. In your example, you're simulating long running transactions that extends beyond your connection timeout within a single thread. If your connection dies of old age while your method is running, you may want to look at ways to optimize your SQL or find other ways to partition your tasks so this doesn't happen.